# Math.round is not a constructor

Tags: javascript

Consider the following:

```
x = function () {}
p = new x()
console.log(p) // ok

Math.z = function () {}
p = new Math.z()
console.log(p) // ok 

p = new Math.round()
console.log(p) // TypeError: function round() { [native code] } is not a constructor
```

So I can use `new` with my own functions, but not with `Math.round`. What makes it so special? Is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's nothing special about `Math.round` You can replicate this behaviour on your own functions:

```
MyClass = function(){};
MyClass.round = function(x){ 
    if(this instanceof MyClass.round)
        throw 'TypeError: MyClass.round is not a constructor';
    return Math.round(x);
}

console.log(MyClass.round(0.5));  // 1
new MyClass.round(); // 'TypeError: MyClass.round is not a constructor'
```

In fact you can use a similar pattern to make the `new` keyword optional on your Class:

```
function MyClass(){
    if(!(this instanceof MyClass)) // If not using new
        return new MyClass();      // Create a new instance and return it

    // Do normal constructor stuff
    this.x = 5;
}

(new MyClass()).x === MyClass().x;
```

As to why `new` doesn't work with built-in functions and methods, this is by design, and documented:

> None of the built-in functions described in this clause that are not constructors shall implement the [[Construct]] internal method unless otherwise specified in the description of a particular function. -- http://es5.github.com/#x15

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't explain why `new foo.bar` works and `new Math.round` doesn't.

Comment: @thg435 Because `Math.round` is designed to fail like that. Just like my function `MyClass.round` is designed to fail. Unless `foo.bar` has been specifically designed to fail in this situation it won't.

Comment: Have you got any proof that "Math.round" is actually designed like that?

Comment: @thg435 The proof is that it throws the error. It's implemented in `C++` so it could be detecting the presence of the `new` keyword differently. But it does detect it and throw an error, by design.

Answer (score 2):

It is a method, that's why you can not put `new` before it.

ps:

```
new alert()        //TypeError: Illegal invocation
new console.log()  //TypeError: Illegal invocation
new function(){}   //OK
```

Comment: You can use `new` with your own methods, e.g. `new foo.bar()`.

Answer (score 1):

Math is a class, so you can create an object from it. Math.round is a method of Math. You cannot create an object from a method.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think so. For starters, there's no such thing as a "class" in javascript.

Comment: true, but you can mimic a class using functions